# Deserialize complex object

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize an object sent by the browser. My object is array of Detail with the name as key. The name is a string and the detail an object with properties.

this is Picture of the javascript object:

[image: Picture of the javascript object]

And this is the JSON String I receive, created with "JSON.stringify(TemplateDetails)":

```
"{\"UDF1-0-div\":{\"UDFtitle\":\"theTitle\",\"DDLType\":\"STRING\",\"defaultValue\":\"defVal\",\"minLength\":\"1\",\"maxLength\":\"6\",\"decimals\":\"\",\"DDLTable\":\"\",\"DDLFilter\":\"\",\"DDLAction\":\"TEST\",\"DDLfontfamily\":\"Verdana\",\"DDLSize\":\"12px\",\"DDLTextAlignment\":\"left\",\"colorTitle\":\"#FFFFFF\",\"colorText\":\"#FFFFFF\"}}"
```

I want to recreate the object in the c# code.

Comment: your Json string is not valid see http://json2csharp.com/ it should not contain escapes for example, you need to fix your json before you can do much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should create a class with all of properties you need :

```
   public class MyClass
    {
    public string DDLAction{ get; set; }
    public string DDLFilter{ get; set; }
    public string DDLSize{ get; set; }

    // put all of your attributes
    //...
    }
```

And for deserialization :

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            MyClass Obj = ser.Deserialize<MyClass>(input);
```

Comment: var models = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<TemplateDetails>(data);

Answer (score 0):

That's not a dictionary, a dictionary looks like this:

```
{
    "objName": {
        ["title", "thetitle"], 
        ["DDLType":"STRING"], 
        ["defaultValue": "defVal"]
    }
}
```

You got a regular object and will have to create it as such.